# From text file to a market matrix format

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am working in Python and I have a matrix stored in a text file. The text file is arranged in such a format:

> row_id, col_id
>  row_id, col_id
>  ...
>  row_id, col_id

row_id and col_id are integers and they take values from 0 to n (in order to know n for row_id and col_id I have to scan the entire file first).

there's no header and row_ids and col_ids appear multiple times in the file, but each combination row_id,col_id appears once. There's no explicit value for each combination row_id,col_id , actually each cell value is 1. The file is almost 1 gigabyte of size.

Unfortunately the file is difficult to handle in the memory, in fact, it is 2257205 row_ids and 122905 col_ids for 26622704 elements. So I was looking for better ways to handle it. Matrix market format could be a way to deal with it.

Is there a fast and memory efficient way to convert this file into a file in a market matrix format (http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html#mtx) using Python?

Comment: Since each logical cell value is either empty or 1, this matrix is essentially a 2D bitmap. Since Python supports integer values of any size, you may be able to store the matrix in memory as a list of integers and be able to determine the value of any cell with lookup and a few bit manipulations. What are the upper limits for for row and col ids?

Comment: The upper limit for rows is 2257205 and for columns is 122905 .

Comment: It would require around 32 GB to represent a bitmap of that size, too big to store in memory. It could instead be stored in a binary file. Too access the bit[row][col] would require computing what byte contains the bit, seeking to that file offset, and reading or writing one byte. That would be a lot of file IO for 26622704 elements, but sounds feasible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a fast and memory efficient way of handling such matrices: using the [sparse matrices offered by SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) (which is the de facto standard in Python for this kind of things).

For a matrix of size `N` by `N`:

```
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix

result = lil_matrix((N, N))  # In order to save memory, one may add: dtype=bool, or dtype=numpy.int8

with open('matrix.csv') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        x, y = map(int, line.split(',', 1))  # The "1" is only here to speed the splitting up
        result[x, y] = 1
```

(or, in one line instead of two: `result[map(int, line.split(',', 1))] = 1`).

The argument `1` given to `split()` is just here to speed things up when parsing the coordinates: it instructs Python to stop parsing the line when the first (and only) comma is found. This can matter some, since you are reading a 1 GB file.

Depending on your needs, you might find one of [the other six sparse matrix representations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#usage-information) offered by SciPy to be better suited.

If you want a faster but also more memory-consuming array, you can use `result = numpy.array(…)` (with NumPy) instead.

Comment: The line.split(',', 1) is a great idea! Thank you. I actually already tried at first lil_matrix, it was fast, but I soon experienced a memory error. So I turned to csc_matrix but it is extremely slow to load values in such a data format.

Comment: If the matrix elements do not change and remain 0 and 1, storing booleans or ints instead of floats should save space. I added a comment in the code to that effect.

Comment: The documentation also recommends the `dok_matrix`: have you tried it? More generally, I can't see anything better than trying multiple sparse matrix representations and checking the one that best suits you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, I found a solution to my problem.

Comment: That's great. Can you share? this will help others!

Comment: In the end I've used a lil_matrix for speed, storing booleans in order to save memory.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something...

The MatrixMarket MM format is a line with the dimensions and "row col value". If you already have rows and cols and all values are 1, simply add the value and that should be it.

Wouldn't it be easier to simply use sed as in

```
n=`wc -l file`
echo "2257205 122905 $n" > file.mm
cat file | sed -e 's/$/ 1/g' >> file.mm
```

That should work if your coordinates are one-offset. If they are zero-offset you should add +1 to each coordinate, simply read coordinates, add one to each of them and print coordx, coordy, "1". Which you can do from the shell, from Awk or from python with very little effort.

Q&D code (untested, produced just as a hint, YMMV and you may want to  preprocess the file to compute some values):

In the shell

```
echo "2257205 122905 $n"
cat file | while read x,y ; do x=$((x+1)); y=$((y+1)); echo "$x $y 1" ; done
```

In python, more or less...

```
f=open("file")
lines=f.readlines()
print 2257205, 122905, len(lines)
for l in lines:
    (x,y) = l.split(' ')
    x = int(x) + 1
    y = int(y) + 1
    print x, y, 1
```

Or am I missing something?